# Bug with tableView.reloadRows(at: self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

While coding a clear button for filter slider I got a bug.

After clear button tap filter should restore data. On first tap all working as it should but on next taps slider is working incorrectly. For reload cell after clear tapped I'm using `tableView.reloadRows(at: self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)`.

Clear button code:

```
@IBAction func clearTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if filterStructure?.filterType == .price {
            filterStructure!.priceRange = " - "
            filterStructure?.filterData[0].isChosen = false
        } else {
            filterStructure?.filterData.mutateEach {filter in
                filter.isChosen = false
            }
        }
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        tableView.reloadRows(at: self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)
    }
```

Cell function:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if filterStructure?.filterType == .price {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PriceFilterCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomFilterTableViewCell
            var min = CGFloat()
            var max = CGFloat()
            var priceArray = [String]()
            filterStructure?.filterData.forEach{priceArray.append($0.filterString)}

            if filterStructure!.isUsed {
                let minAndMax = filterStructure?.priceRange!.components(separatedBy: " - ")
                min = CGFloat(Double(minAndMax![0]) ?? 0)
                max = CGFloat(Double(minAndMax![1]) ?? 0)
            } else {
                min = CGFloat(Double(priceArray.min()!) ?? 0)
                max = CGFloat(Double(priceArray.max()!) ?? 0)
            }
            print(min) //always 3200
            print(max) //always 6500
            cell.priceSlider.minValue = CGFloat(Double(priceArray.min()!) ?? 0)
            cell.priceSlider.maxValue = CGFloat(Double(priceArray.max()!) ?? 0)
            cell.priceSlider.selectedMinValue = min
            cell.priceSlider.selectedMaxValue = max
            cell.priceSlider.maxDistance = max
            cell.priceSlider.delegate = self
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none
            self.tableView.rowHeight = 75.0
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterSecondCell", for: indexPath)
            if let cell = cell as? FilterSecondTableViewCell {
                cell.filterParameterTextLabel?.text = filterStructure?.filterData[indexPath.row].filterString
                if filterStructure?.filterData[indexPath.row].isChosen == true {
                    cell.checkImageView.isHidden = false
                }
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

CustomFilterTableViewCell:

```
import UIKit
import RangeSeekSlider

class CustomFilterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var priceSlider: RangeSeekSlider!
    
    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "CustomFilterTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        priceSlider.minLabelFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14.0)!
        priceSlider.maxLabelFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14.0)!
        priceSlider.minDistance = 1.0
        priceSlider.numberFormatter.numberStyle = .none
        priceSlider.tintColor = UIColor(named: "Light GreyLP")
        priceSlider.step = 1.0
        priceSlider.enableStep = true
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

[image: Bug demonstration]

Comment: Please share filterStructure.

Comment: @Asteroid

Optional(LP.ProductFilter(filterType: LP.FilterTypes.price, filterData: [LP.Filter(filterString: "3200", isChosen: false), LP.Filter(filterString: "3900", isChosen: false), LP.Filter(filterString: "5400", isChosen: false), LP.Filter(filterString: "6500", isChosen: false)], priceRange: Optional(" - ")))

Answer (score 0):

It seems like each time you click the button, it resets the value to previous selected value.

I don't get why you don't set  cell.priceSlider.minValue to min and maxValue to max.